# Lost iPad doesn't connect to WiFi

Tags: ipad, icloud, unlock, screen-lock

A family member's iPad 2 (WiFi), which is connected to my old Apple ID has been locked with a message that says she has to pay $30 to someone online. I said not to pay and I went online, logged into the iCloud account that was attached to the iPad, and removed the Lost status so she could unlock it again.

However, the iPad is still in Lost mode because it can't connect to WiFi (to receive the 'unlost' command from iCloud) and to connect it needs to be unlocked.

There is an option to enter a passcode but the old passcode didn't work.

Any ideas on how I can recover it? Wiping is an option since there isn't much on it anyway.

Comment: My answer I've given assumes that the iPad doesn't have other "remembered" Wifi locations. If this user has connected anywhere before (friends house, school, etc) you may be able to temporarily get a signal, and it would send the message to iCloud.com.

Comment: The WiFi worked at the owners house and my house but it doesn't connect now. I'm going to reset it later today. Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: Good luck! If you need assistance, don't be shy about clicking the "source" button in my answer for a nice looking guide.

Comment: **[Ring Apple](https://support.apple.com/HT201232) before you compound this further.** They will be more than interested in how/why/what that ransom is & how anyone managed to put it there.

Answer (score 2):

You can always restore an iPad that’s locked if you have possession of the device and the iCloud account. Also, connecting it over USB to iTunes will often allow you to get it unlocked promptly and on High Sierra - the Mac can share it’s network connection to iOS devices over USB so you don’t even need WiFi on the iPad for it to connect back to the internet and receive an update from iCloud/Apple for the unlock commands that are pending delivery.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, even if this was connected up to a computer and opened in iTunes, it would still require you to unlock the device in order to "trust the device".

It stinks, but I think you've already alluded to the remaining option here: [Use iTunes to "restore" the iPad.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204184) (Instructions half-way down).